# Elasticsearch: get current running snapshot operation

Tags: elasticsearch, ansible, elasticsearch-2.0

Assume, need to automate the snapshot restoring of 2 or more snapshots to elastic cluster.
It is necessary to detect, that snapshot operation is completed before next api call: `_snaphot/<repository>/<snapshot>/_restore`.
If I call while snapshot is restoring, cluster responses 503.

I tried to use thread pool api with running snapshot operation:
`curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cat/thread_pool?h=snapshot.active`
But, it returns 0 anyway.

What is proper way to do get info about current running restore operation?

UPDATE:
An example how have it managed to work with ansible:

```
- name: shell | restore latest snapshot
  uri:
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:9200/_snapshot/{{ es_snapshot_repository }}/snapshot_name/_restore"
    method: "POST"
    body: '{"index_settings":{"index.number_of_replicas": 0}}'
    body_format: json

- name: shell | get state of active recovering operations | log indices
  uri:
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:9200/_recovery?active_only"
    method: "GET"
  register: response
  until: "response.json == {}"
  retries: 6
  delay: 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can monitor status of indices being restored using [Indices Recovery API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-recovery.html).

The easiest way of doing this is looking at the `stage` property:

> `init`: Recovery has not started
>
> `index`: Reading index meta-data and copying bytes from source to destination
>
> `start`: Starting the engine;
>
> `opening` the index for use translog: Replaying transaction log
>
> `finalize`: Cleanup done: Complete
>
> `done`: Complete

Parameter `active_only` returns info about shards that are not in `done` state:
`http://127.0.0.1:9200/_recovery?active_only`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, let me test it

Comment: thanks again, I used recovery api, see an example I added to question.